# Sorting an array of names in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have to write a procedure in assembly that sort an array of upto 20 Names,
max 11 characters. My programs accepts 3 records but keeps crashing at
everything else and I can't get it to sort. I'm using bubble sort.
BTW, I can't change anything in C++ since this is an assignment.

These first 3 lines are from the C++ code.

```
extern "C" void Sort (char [] [11], char [], double [], long);

char Names [20] [11];

Sort (Names, LetterGrades, Averages, NumStudents - 1);

_Sort proc

      mov ecx, [esp +16]
      dec ecx

L1:   push ecx
    mov esi, [esp + 4]

L2:   mov eax, [esi]
      cmp [esi + 11], eax
    jg L3
      xchg eax,[esi + 11]
      mov [esi],eax

L3:   add esi,11
      loop L2

      pop ecx
      loop L1

L4: ret

_Sort endp
```

Comment: The C declaration is for a 2 dimensional array of char, your assembly code is for a 1 dimensional array of char*.

Comment: Are there comments in your actual assignment code?  I would have been beaten for turning in an assembly project without comments.  To understand your code without comments, I have to figure out how your system pushes arguments onto the stack.  Also, your label names aren't particularly descriptive of what you're trying to accomplish.  These 'style' issues, although they won't directly fix your problem, could help you understand your own code and it's faults better.

Comment: My professor is not picky about them, but I do understand they help when used. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should compare every character (A) of every name against the corresponding character (B) of all the other names, then, eventually, swap the two names if B and all characters preceding it are smaller than A and characters before. Right now that's my only idea but I can't translate it in code, I should think about it still some time...

I tried to explain it as best as I could, anyway I'm sorry if it's a mess.. =)

Comment: What you are saying makes sense descriptively, but I can't figure out how to make it work in my program. I've been trying many different things but somehow none that works.